# Microsoft API call to update win32LobAppRegistryRule

Tags: api, winapi, graph, request, intune

I'm struggling with a Microsoft Graph API call to update the detection rule of an Intune Application. I will detail all API requests I've made beneath along with the issues encountered.

I believe it's an issue with the `@odata.type`'s and how they're nested within each other.
I've been making use of this MS doc for [updating a WIN32 LOB App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/intune-apps-win32lobapp-update?view=graph-rest-1.0) via the graph API. Within this doc you can see an example request for updating the app. The entire request body is shown in JSON format. I will also post it beneath.

```
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/deviceAppManagement/mobileApps/{mobileAppId}
Content-type: application/json
Content-length: 2134

{
  "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.win32LobApp",
  "displayName": "Display Name value",
  "description": "Description value",
  "publisher": "Publisher value",
  "largeIcon": {
    "@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.mimeContent",
    "type": "Type value",
    "value": "dmFsdWU="
  },
  "isFeatured": true,
  "privacyInformationUrl": "https://example.com/privacyInformationUrl/",
  "informationUrl": "https://example.com/informationUrl/",
  "owner": "Owner value",
  "developer": "Developer value",
  "notes": "Notes value",
  "publishingState": "processing",
  "committedContentVersion": "Committed Content Version value",
  "fileName": "File Name value",
  "size": 4,
  "installCommandLine": "Install Command Line value",
  "uninstallCommandLine": "Uninstall Command Line value",
  "applicableArchitectures": "x86",
  "minimumFreeDiskSpaceInMB": 8,
  "minimumMemoryInMB": 1,
  "minimumNumberOfProcessors": 9,
  "minimumCpuSpeedInMHz": 4,
  "rules": [
    {
      "@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.win32LobAppRegistryRule",
      "ruleType": "requirement",
      "check32BitOn64System": true,
      "keyPath": "Key Path value",
      "valueName": "Value Name value",
      "operationType": "exists",
      "operator": "equal",
      "comparisonValue": "Comparison Value value"
    }
  ],
  "installExperience": {
    "@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.win32LobAppInstallExperience",
    "runAsAccount": "user",
    "deviceRestartBehavior": "allow"
  },
  "returnCodes": [
    {
      "@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.win32LobAppReturnCode",
      "returnCode": 10,
      "type": "success"
    }
  ],
  "msiInformation": {
    "@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.win32LobAppMsiInformation",
    "productCode": "Product Code value",
    "productVersion": "Product Version value",
    "upgradeCode": "Upgrade Code value",
    "requiresReboot": true,
    "packageType": "perUser",
    "productName": "Product Name value",
    "publisher": "Publisher value"
  },
  "setupFilePath": "Setup File Path value",
  "minimumSupportedWindowsRelease": "Minimum Supported Windows Release value"
}
```

What I've done is taken a section of this API `PATCH` call, excluding the parts I do not wish to update, leaving just the rules list.

The beneath request body beneath is accepted and a `204 status code` is returned when sending a PATCH request to the correct endpoint, however, no data within the detection rule properties is updated. In this example, I'm trying to update the  `comparisonValue`.

```
{
    "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.win32LobApp",
    "rules": [
        {
            "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.win32LobAppRegistryRule",
            "ruleType": "detection",
            "check32BitOn64System": false,
            "keyPath": "HKLM\\SOFTWARE\\Test",
            "valueName": "ActuarialAddinUpdate",
            "operationType": "string",
            "operator": "equal",
            "comparisonValue": "2022.09.20"
        }
    ]
}
```

A second MS doc I've been using is this one that specifically talks about [updating a win32LobAppRegistryRule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/intune-apps-win32lobappregistryrule?view=graph-rest-1.0).

It is clearly stated in the documentation that:

1. A **complex type** to store registry rule data for a Win32 LOB app.
2. Inherits from **win32LobAppRule**

Starting with the `complex type`, I'm unsure as to what this means. The *Inherits from win32LobAppRule* makes me think that the request I'm sending where the rule update being nested in the win32LobAppRule `@odata.type` is correct.

I am able to update the DisplayName of the Intune application using the beneath request:

```
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/deviceAppManagement/mobileApps/*appid*

{
    "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.win32LobApp",
    "displayName": "NAME DOES CHANGE"
}
```

This patch request works! But it's not the name we want to change, it's the detection rule properties. Seeing as this works, I assume once again that the request I'm including in the body should work.

I will update this question as I continue to debug this issue. The documentation provided is extremely vague and doesn't contain a good example of how to update the properties of a Intune Application.

Here's a screenshot of the properties I'm trying to modify via the api:

[image: Intune App properties]

Please let me know if you require any further information on what I'm trying to achieve. Happy to provide more. Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: I believe you should use `beta` endpoint, and not `v1.0` endpoint.  
Correct URL is: `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/deviceAppManagement/mobileApps/{mobileAppId}`
Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/intune-shared-mobileapp-get?view=graph-rest-beta

Comment: @J-M I think both v1.0 and beta have this functionality otherwise I wouldn't have been able to update the displayName